# Why my template function is not a valid match in this call?

Tags: c++, function, templates, return

i made the following code to convert number to string and reverse
in the commented part of code i want to make the function  type a template
thinking that it will acquire the type according to context "e.g if i assign
it to int variable the function will be of type int " but this not occur and compiler
give error message

```
D:\computer science\project\stringToint.cpp In function 'int main()':
49  25  D:\computer science\project\stringToint.cpp [Error] no matching function for call to 'intstr(const char [10])'
49  25  D:\computer science\project\stringToint.cpp [Error] candidate is:
17  21  D:\computer science\project\stringToint.cpp template<class T> T intstr(std::string)
```

i think that their was error in using stringstream object
but i was successful in achieving the function to work if
i specify the type of function but this will make me write 
different function for every type

is i miss understand some thing please help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
string strint (T oty)
{
    string ity;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<oty;
    ss>>ity;
    return ity;
}
/*
template<typename T> 
T intstr (string oty)
{
    T ity;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<oty;
    ss>>ity;
    return ity;
}
*/
int intstr (string oty)
{
    int ity;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<oty;
    ss>>ity;
    return ity;
}
signed char charstr (string oty)
{
    signed char ity;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<oty;
    ss>>ity;
    return ity;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    signed char c;
    string s;
    s=strint(123);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    i=intstr("123456789");
    cout<<i<<endl;
    c=charstr("2");
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand these downvotes. There is a small piece of code exposing problem, error message is provided. Quite good for first question asked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should explicitly specify template parameter for function, since compiler can't `deduce` T, because there are no parameters of type `T` in function args. Like

```
intstr<int>("123456789");
```

Comment: ok thanks but why was the compiler saying no matching function for call to 'intstr

Comment: @AhmedMazher because, if there is only template version - it can't be called without template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @ForEveR i now reduced my code to look like this and it is working well 
i hope it is the best solution of converting number to string and vise verse
using stringstream
thanks alot

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T1,typename T2> 
T2 strint (T1 oty)
{
    T2 ity;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<oty;
    ss>>ity;
    return ity;
}

int main()
{ 
    cout<< strint <string,int>("1234") <<endl;
    cout<< strint <int,string>(456) <<endl;
    cout<< strint <string,float>("3.14") <<endl;
    cout<< strint <string,char>("3") <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```